# Force Google Apps users to change password periodically

Tags: google-apps-script, passwords

I'm wondering if anyone has updated the following script for the new "Admin SDK Directory Service" as I currently get an error with the "UserManager" is not defined.

The original script is from this site (Thank you),
http://www.googleappsscript.org/home/force-google-apps-users-to-change-password-periodically

I'm not a developer but I have used this script before and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

This is the line that is giving you the error:

```
//get all users in domain
var users = UserManager.getAllUsers();
```

That API is now deprecated:

[Google Documentation - google-apps/provisioning](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/)

In order to use the new API, it must be explicitly enabled in your Apps Script editor.  And you will need a domain name.

[Google Support - What is a domain?](https://support.google.com/a/answer/177483?hl=en)

If you have a domain name, you can use this example code, to get a list of all the users:

[Apps Script Documentation - Admin SDK Directory Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#list_all_users)

The code you were using would need to be totally re-written.  It's not really what stackoverflow is meant for.

Comment: Sandy,   Thank you for the reply. I wasn't expecting someone to rewrite the code for me. As the original script was from here I was hoping someone had updated/rewritten it for themselves and would be willing to share it.